# Html Email Content using PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I am using PHP Code to send email 
Here is my code

```
<?php

$message ="<html><head><title>Enquiry Email</title></head><body>";
$message .= '<div style="float:left"><img src="url" /></div>';
$message .="You got a new Enquiry From Following <br/>"; 
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
        if(!empty($value)){
            $message.="<strong>".ucwords($key)."</strong>: ".$value."<br/>";
        }
}
$message .= 'test content</body></html>';
//echo $message; exit;
//$message=rtrim(chunk_split(base64_encode($message)));
$to      = 'test@someeamil.com';
$subject = 'New Enquiry';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
//$headers . ='Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64';
$headers .= "From: test email<test@someemail.in>\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

i got email in this format

```
Subject: New Enquiry

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

From: test email<test@someemail.in>

Message-Id: <20120110134752.3AE7B2A91E@somename.in> Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2012 19:17:52 +0530 (IST) X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAA== X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAA==


<html><head><title>Enquiry Email</title></head><body><div style="flaot:left"><img src="linkurl" /></div>You got a new Enquiry From Following <br/><strong>Customer</strong>: Customer<br/><strong>Title</strong>: Mr.<br/><strong>Fistname</strong>: gurpreet<br/><strong>Lastname</strong>: Singh<br/><strong>Telephone</strong>: 212344556<br/><strong>Email</strong>: test@test.com<br/><strong>Address</strong>: addrewss Vi<br/><strong>Catalogue</strong>: Catalogue<br/><strong>Meeting</strong>: Meeting at my home / office<br/><strong>Internet</strong>: Internet<br/>some name </body></html>
```

But now when i try to send at gmail server  it gives proper output in HTML Format.

Thanks!

Comment: "But now when i try to send at gmail server it gives proper output in HTML Format." this sounds like you have no problem. What IS your problem?

Comment: Does your e-mail client support HTML e-mail?

Comment: @KaiQing : i am trying to send emal on other client read emessage 

Message-Id: <20120110134752.3AE7B2A91E@somename.in> Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2012 19:17:52 +0530 (IST) X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAA== X-Brightmail-Tracker: AAAAAA==

Comment: so you want to preserve the message ID and extra header info in all clients? Is this for whatever brightmail tracker is?

Comment: i don't have idea. in other client i got got message with <html>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 3rd-party email software library (e.g. [SwiftMailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org)) for easier email handling.

Comment: sorry i don't want to use third party

Comment: why insist? I don't think you can write a mailer PHP with threshold control, spam management & attachment easily.

Answer (score 0):

Header should be in proper format and remove the sample code is as follows:

```
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"
             . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n"
             . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 


    $message ="--{$mime_boundary}\n"
             . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"
             . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
```

Your `From` tag must be before `MIME-Version`. The above code is working fine. Rearrange your header.